# accepting last field on a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf

HI: How can I accept the last field entered when the window closes?
could be a chkbox or textbox or ...
Thanks

Comment: Your question, it makes no sense.  'accept'?  What does this mean?  Pls clarify your question with details about exactly what you are doing and what isn't going right.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "accept?"

Comment: MartyIX has the right idea. sorry about using the wrong term.
thanks

Comment: besides the wrong term "accept" the idea is when you close a window in XPF how do you know which was the last field having the focus.

Answer (score 2):

In normal binding data will be updated (by default) in lostfucus event.If you want to update the data when you type in the control use UpdateSourceTrigger=property. Iam not sure is that your requirement.

eg. Binding="{Binding Path = Privilege, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

Comment: As long you use that attribute will work.
first:
   I beleive that will work with one condition ,what if UpdateSourceTrigger= PropertyLostFocus?
2nd:
at the click of any button do you loose focus if you are in a text field ?